# Adding SSD to T420 with ultrabay HDD on bitlocker encrypted system

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, ssd, bios, bitlocker

I want to add SSD to Thinkpad T420 with ultrabay HDD. Existing HDD is bitlocker encrypted as per company policy. I have got Admin rights to system.

- If I add an SSD drive, will this be ecrypted?
- Do I need to change some settings in the BIOS?
- Can I make the system dual boot with Ubuntu on the SSD?

I just wanted to know if this is possible before investing money in an SSD.

Answer (score 2):

I have installed new drive so answering:

- If I add an SSD drive, will this be ecrypted? **No**
- Do I need to change some settings in the BIOS? **No**
- Can I make the system dual boot with Ubuntu on the SSD? **Yes**

I have observed that Bitlocker Encrypted drive keeps on asking for recovery keys every time I boot from that drive (after entering bitlocker pin). This might be because boot configurations are changed. I have not figured it out yet how to stop encrypted drive asking for recovery keys while boot.